# Bootstrap input form , search button and different buttons in same row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container-fluid"><br/>
   <h3 >Content Mangement</h3><br/>
   <div class="container-fluid"></div><br/>
 <div class="row"><br/>
  <div class="col-md-2"><br/>
       <input class="form-control custom-input-width pull-left" type="text"> <br/>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="col-md-10 text-right"><br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button><br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Content</button><br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Reoder</button><br/>
  </div><br/>
```

I want to put code like this. I am typing for last 3 4 days:

[image: f]

I want this text , input form and button in same line:

[image: h]

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is broken so if you correct your sturcture to a proper structue we can get what you desire with  your existing approach with some css fixes , however i can suggest better way to layout this thing if you would like because this way is little improper to do this type of layout design.

However with your current approach a more correct structure looks like this :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-4">
            <h3>Content Mangement</h3>
         </div>

        <div class="col col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <input class="form-control custom-input-width" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Content</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Reoder</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then with some padding fix you can achieve the design with your current approach